# Using an iframe for a form help

Tags: forms, html, mobile, iframe

I need to add an html form to my homepage so I have added an iframe using raw html. Everything works correctly on the desktop but when I try to use it on mobile it gets messed up. Instead of our mobile website being loaded completely, it just gets loaded into the iframe. I am not sure why that happens.

Is there anything to add that can stop this from happening or another way to add the form code in? I have tried just adding the form code in without the iframe but the html code messes up the other aspects of the page (such as drop downs and buttons).

I can not use a form builder plugin since the form has to be submitted into our system and not sent to an email address.

Looking for any help you can provide! Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
<iframe style="background: #FFFFFF;" src="formname.html" name="cent-form"
width="400px" height="500px" align="right" frameborder="0" marginwidth="5px"
marginheight="5px" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a fully qualified path name for the `src` parameter, i.e. `src="https://example.com/path/to/formname.html"`?

Comment: yes, I have the full path name in the actual code.

Comment: if you remove all attributes from the iframe what happens `<iframe src="formname.html"></iframe>`

Comment: It still loads the mobile website in the iframe.